# Add bathymetry lines to ggplot using marmap package and getNOAA.bathy

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I am wanting to add bathymetry lines to a map plot I am looking at. I am plotting points off the coast and we are interested as to how close to the continental shelf they are. I have seen a package called Marmap - but now I am using ggplot as it gives a higher resolution.

The code I've seen for getting bathymetry lines is this:

```
library(marmap)

Peru.bath <- getNOAA.bathy (lon1 = -90, lon2 = -70, lat1 = -20, 
                            lat2 = -2, resolution = 10) 

plot(Peru.bath)
```

The code I'm using which I want to add the bathymetry lines to is below:

```
coast_map <- fortify(map("worldHires", fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE))
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=coast_map, map=coast_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region),
                    fill="white", color="black") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank())
gg <- gg + xlab("") + ylab("")
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=data.frame(region="Peru"), map=coast_map,
                    aes(map_id=region), fill="gray") 
gg <- gg + xlim(-90,-70) + ylim(-20,-2)
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg
```

Therefore I assumed it would be

```
gg <- gg + Peru.bath
```

However I am getting 'Error: Don't know how to add Peru.bath to a plot'

NB Just to make it clear, I do not have bathymetry data, I just wish to plot known shelf lines onto a map I have created, if that is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to (i) add isobath lines to your map and (ii) determine the depth of your data points using `get.depth()` it would be much easier to stick with standard plots (`marmap` is designed to work with these). As a matter of fact, the "better resolution" you mention has nothing to do with base graphics nor `ggplot2`. In your example, the coastline you're plotting comes from the "worldHires" dataset from package `mapdata` and it has nothing to do with `ggplot2`. Indeed, you can add the same coastline on `marmap` plots.

Here is some code to produce two more than decent maps using base graphics and `marmap`:

```
library(marmap) ; library(mapdata)

# Get bathymetric data
dat <- getNOAA.bathy(-90,-70,-20,-2,res=4, keep=TRUE)

# Create nice color palettes
blues <- c("lightsteelblue4", "lightsteelblue3", "lightsteelblue2", "lightsteelblue1")
greys <- c(grey(0.6), grey(0.93), grey(0.99))

## First option for plotting
plot(dat, land=TRUE, n=100, lwd=0.03)
map("worldHires", res=0, add=TRUE)

# Second option
plot(dat, im=TRUE, land=TRUE, bpal=list(c(min(dat),0,blues),c(0,max(dat),greys)), lwd=.05, las=1 )
map("worldHires", res=0, lwd=0.7, add=TRUE)

# Add -200m and -1000m isobath
plot(dat, deep=-200, shallow=-200, step=0, lwd=0.5, drawlabel=TRUE, add=TRUE)
plot(dat, deep=-1000, shallow=-1000, step=0, lwd=0.3, drawlabel=TRUE, add=TRUE)
```

Note that the resolution used here is not the highest possible. the `res` argument of `getNOAA.bathy()` is set to 4 here. This downloads a 2.7Mb dataset that can be saved locally by setting the `keep` argument to `TRUE`. The highest resolution possible would be `res=1`, but in my opinion, it is overkill for such a wide geographical scale. This code produces the 2 plots below:

[image: First option: wireframe plot]
[image: Second option: image plot]

Comment: This is fantastic @Benoit! Thankyou so much. However, since this post I have actually continued my endeavours in ggplot using a google maps as the base package as the satellite ones show some topographic data which was close to bathymetry- is there a way I can add this as a ggplot base map? I tried fortify but it says ggplot does not recognise class of bathy? Many thanks.

Comment: Please, see my second answer below: I've included an example for plotting bathy objects with ggplot2 using a new function.

Answer (score 10):

I've just updated the development version of marmap on github. You can install it with:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ericpante/marmap")
```

A function `autoplot.bathy()` for plotting bathy objects with ggplot2 is now included. Be sure to check it's help file and the examples to see what's possible. Here is an example with your dataset `dat`:

```
library(marmap) ; library(ggplot2)
dat <- getNOAA.bathy(-90,-70,-20,-2,res=4, keep=TRUE)

# Plot bathy object using custom ggplot2 functions
autoplot(dat, geom=c("r", "c"), colour="white", size=0.1) + scale_fill_etopo()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Running a bit short on time this morning, but this should help you get started (and, can no doubt be improved by other R geo folks:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(ggplot2)
library(marmap)
library(Grid2Polygons)

coast_map <- fortify(map("worldHires", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE))

Peru.bath <- getNOAA.bathy (lon1 = -90, lon2 = -70, lat1 = -20,
                            lat2 = -2, resolution = 10)

peru_bathy_df <- Grid2Polygons(as.SpatialGridDataFrame(Peru.bath), 
                               level=TRUE, pretty=TRUE)
peru_bathy_map <- fortify(peru_bathy_df)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=peru_bathy_map, map=peru_bathy_map,
                    aes(map_id=id), color="black", fill="white")
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=coast_map, map=coast_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region),
                    fill="white", color="black")
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=data.frame(region="Peru"), map=coast_map,
                    aes(map_id=region), fill="steelblue")
gg <- gg + xlim(-90,-70) + ylim(-20,-2)
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

[image]

Obviously you want a better picture than that, but the basic idea is to get it converted into an object that ggplot can handle (so, a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame). Lots of good non-ggplot examples in the bathy and Grid2Polygons help.

NOTE: these take some time to convert/render and the bathy examples do show a way to do this without ggplot that will be *much* faster.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - Looks great! However, I was wondering if anyone knew if it is possible to keep the lines and add depth info. I have used the get.depth function for each of my datapoints I wish to plot, but not sure how to add it to a plot (preferably using ggplot).. Maybe @Benoit would be able to point me in the right direction?